# Layout Elements Not Showing - Android 4.3 Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-layout

I encountered a problem while testing my app on a Samsung Galaxy S3 in 4.3.

Layout elements such as ImageViews, ActionBar, are not appearing on screen.
The only working element is GoogleMaps Fragment.

It only displays black instead of showing the layout set in the XML file.

I'm developping an Android Application targetting SDK 23.
My app is working perfectly on Lollipop devices.
I tested it on an API 19 Emulator and it works too.

Here's a picture of the actual problem

[Black displaying in place of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvSNY.png)

I hope you guys can help me to sort this out.

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was that I was calling these lines window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
   window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS); Without testing if my device was >= Lollipop